# Python task runner with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to a write super simple task runner with asyncio.

Basically, my goal is to run 100 requests to google as tasks, whilst also being be able to handle tasks being added at a later time.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import asyncio
import socket
import time

import aiohttp
import requests

class MyScheduler:
    def __init__(self, wait=2):
        self.work = []
        self.wait = wait

    def set_initial_callback(self, callback, **kwargs):
        self.initial_callback = callback
        self.initial_callback_args = kwargs

    async def add_task(self, callback, **kwargs):
        task = asyncio.create_task(callback(**kwargs))
        self.work.append(task)

    async def _run(self):
        while self.work:
            task = self.work.pop()
            await  task
            if len(self.work) == 0:
                await asyncio.sleep(self.wait)

    async def set_things_up(self, callback, **kwargs):
        task = asyncio.create_task(callback(**kwargs))
        self.work.append(task)
        await self._run()

    def go(self):
        asyncio.run(self.set_things_up(self.initial_callback, **self.initial_callback_args))


async def google(n):
    if n == 100:
        return None
    await s.add_task(google, n=n + 1)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://h...content-available-to-author-only...n.org/get') as resp:
            print(resp.status)

t = time.time()
s = MyScheduler(wait=1)
s.set_initial_callback(google, n=1)
s.go()
print(time.time() - t)
```

I benchmarked this against sequentally running requests, and I did see a massive speed up. It's still super rough, but I'd love some pointers on how  I could improve my code in terms of readability/exploiting async stuff better.

Answer (score 3):

I actually just started learning `asyncio` a couple days ago, so I won't be able to comment too deeply. I do see a few things though:

Disregarding asyncio for a sec, I think `google` could be set up better. You have the base case of the recursion as `n == 100`, and are incrementing `n` in each recursive call. To easily allow the caller to decide how many time to run, I'd reverse how `n` is being handled. I would decrement it each call, and set the base case as `n <= 0`. With how you have it now, say the caller wanted it to run 1000 times, they would need to call it as

```
google(-900)
```

which is a little wonky. I'd change the first bit to:

```
async def google(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return None

    await s.add_task(google, n=n - 1)

. . .
```

---

I'm not sure recursion is the cleanest tool for the job here. I'm also not sure entirely why you're using a job queue or why you're using a elaborate class here unless the goal is to be able to handle jobs being added at a later time.

If your goal is just to initiate many requests and wait on them at the same time, you could just [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=gather#asyncio.gather) them:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio as a

# google no longer cares about how many times it runs
# That is arguably beyond the responsibilities of a function intended to make requests
async def google():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://h...content-available-to-author-only...n.org/get') as resp:
            print(resp.status)

async def start_requests(n_requests: int):
    routines = [google() for _ in range(n_requests)]  # Create a list of reqeust-making coroutines
    await a.gather(*routines)  # Unpack the routines into gather (since gather is var-arg)
```

---

Also, instead of doing timing using a single attempt and plain subtraction, it would be more accurate to use `timeit`:

```
from timeit import timeit

print("t:", timeit(lambda: a.run(start_requests(10)), number=20))  # number is the amount of tests to do
```

I'm assuming there's no issue using `timeit` for async code.

Comment: thanks for the feedback!  I should have added, yes the goal is to be able to handle jobs being added at a later time, as it offers more flexibility. :) Do you have any recommendations for how I could implement a graceful shutdown?